# SUMPRODUCT with AND criteria on Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, sumproduct

I'm trying to count all apples, oranges and mango of a specific month and year, but the formula doesn't work right now. Is there anything obvious that I'm doing wrong here?

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(TEXT(A:A,"MMYYYY")="052020"), --(B:B={"apple","orange","mango"}))
```

[Link to the sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JquAm2p1aNVtAg6aq0vJ9h-oHO0VYEZbcdZ8xA3Px6w/edit#gid=0)

```
Colum A    Column B

May 2020   apple
May 2020   apple
May 2020   banana
May 2020   orange
May 2020   mango

Jun 2020   papaya
Jun 2020   mango
Aug 2020   apple
Oct 2020   apple
Oct 2020   orange
Oct 2020   banana
```

Comment: Confused - is this excel or google sheet? you tag excel but say google sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I found it :)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(  (TEXT(B9:B19,"MMYYYY")="052020")*  ISNUMBER(MATCH(C9:C19, 
 {"apple","orange","mango"},0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=COUNTA(IFNA(QUERY(B7:C, 
 "select B 
  where month(B)+1 = 5 
    and year(B) = 2020 
    and C matches 'banana|mango|apple'"))
```

[image]

or:

```
=COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER(B7:B, 
 TEXT(B7:B, "mmyyyy")="052020", 
 REGEXMATCH(C7:C, "banana|mango|apple"))
```

[image]